# Preventing a user from running a script that should only be run by a CRON job?

Tags: mysql, security, http, cron

I have a contact form on my site which uses $HTTP requests instead of reloading on the form submit. It's a really awesome feature, but it also opens up some nasty doors.

My contact form sends an HTML "Thank You" email to the people who contacted me. I was worried about that functionality being abused and used to send emails from "me."

My solution was to create a database and some logic on the server-side of things to prevent a user from sending more than three emails a day. It does this by adding their IP address and the number of times they've sent an email today to a MySQL database.

Since I want people to have a fresh start the next day, and I don't want to keep a list of IP addresses lying around, I created a CRON job that runs every night and truncates the table containing those records.

The problem here is that I've just reopened my original problem, because someone who can figure out how to send $http requests to send emails as me, can figure out how to trunicate the table and send more emails.

I have a shared hosting account at GoDaddy. Is there anything server-wise I can do to prevent the script from being run anywhere other than as a CRON job?

Specifically, my first thought was to only allow the IP address assigned to my server to run the script. But, I've read that the IP addresses running your CRON job might now be the same IP address your domain is assigned to for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Cant you just add a date selector to your SQL query and only select those that match on the given date? You can truncate the table as a cron job by deleting entries daily that are over $DATE+36 hours.

Comment: I thought about that. The problem is that I would have to set the script up to run more rapidly than every day, and I don't want to commit to using that bandwidth to go through every record. I.E. unless I was running every five minutes and someone sent their third email at 12:01 AM they wouldn't be eligible to send more emails for very near two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an shared hosting account or without access to the command line you can work with an secret parameter over http(s). I don't know if godaddy allow this, but you can try using wget or lynx in your cronjob call. Or use an independent cronjob service for that http-call.

Create an longer string randomly, save it in your script and call the cronjob with this as parameter. Keep this string secret. In your script: compare the parameter with the saved secret.

eg: /usr/bin/wget --quiet http://example.org/your-cronjob.php?secret=random-string-with-20-chars-or-more

Comment: Since I have a tiny portfolio, I think this was a good option. I set a get variable equal to the result of a PHP password hash, and the value of that GET variable is also equal to the result of a PHP password hash. (Both values are over 100 characters.) I simply check the password hash results against the GET variable name and the value of that GET variable.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you an do

- Use permissions to ensure that only the user who owns the cron job can execute the file e.g. 700 (rwx------)
- Have the script check to see if who it is being run by and continue appropriately (whoami)
- have mysql only allow the user who can run the cron job interact with the relevant database (grant permissions).
- Have the script check to see if it's being run interactively or not - check for the existence of `PS1` or use `tty -s`
- You could set an environment variable in the crontab file and check for it's existence in your script.
- You could get the pid of the process and find it's parent then check it's crond.

There are probably other things too and most likely using more than one or all of the above is a good way to go.

Of course, if you have people who have access to root credentials then all bets are off as they can do what they want anyway.